# Failed to load PDF in web page while publishing in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf

I am doing a website in MVC4.  I want to show pdf in my web page but it is working nice when I run on local host. The problem comes while publishing.

It shows failed to load pdf document.  Here is my my controller code is

```
public FileResult DisplayPDF()
{
    return File("~/App_Data/invoice.pdf", "application/pdf");
}
```

and my View page is

```
 @Html.ActionLink("View pdf", "Displaypdf", null, new { target = "_blank" })<br />
```

How to resole that issue?  Please help me.

Comment: Do you have the PDF set to content? (right click the file and set the build action to content)

Comment: Hey Paul ..Whoo its working .thanks for your help.i have been trying for the past twodays..

Comment: No problem. I posted the answer to it as well if you want to mark it as the answer. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the PDF build action to content (right click the file and set the build action to content)